# Get dataframe rows with complicated rule

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe object that holds tcp data. Example

[image]

I am interested in finding rows that fit a complicated rule:

1. The rows should have ssize between 268 and 280
2. The following packet (or the one after that) in that connection (which is identified by the combination of client_id, client_port) should be between -54 and -60
3. The packet before the one in range 268 and 280 for the given client should come from a different port.

For instance, in this image, the highlighted row is interesting
[image]

The ssize is in the range that we want, the following packet is ssize -57 which is also in the range we require of that packet (or the one after), and the packet previously sent or received by the client 5186 is from a different port, port 54771 while the 275 and -57 are from port 54772.

I would like to find all rows like the highlighted one. I can do this with a for loop easy enough, but it takes forever and is very inefficient. I'm terrible with pandas and groupbys and applies and stuff like that. Would appreciate any help.

Text sample:

```
       client_id  client_port      timestamp  ssize
25721       5186        54771  1621382531757    -47
25739       5186        54771  1621382531818     23
26136       5186        54772  1621382534346    275
26158       5186        54772  1621382534582    -57
26159       5186        54772  1621382534583    -43
26166       5186        54772  1621382534618     35
26187       5186        54772  1621382534749    -46
26188       5186        54772  1621382534772   -166
26189       5186        54772  1621382534772    -37
26190       5186        54772  1621382534772    -59
```

Expected output: Either a dataframe containing only the interesting rows, or a list or series of the indices of the interesting rows. So in the example provided, it's a new dataframe just with row index 26136

Comment: Will you please send a text sample of your dataframe, not just a screenshot? I can't copy/paste the dataframe for myself.

Comment: Do you need anything else?

Comment: Well, one more thing. Based on the snippet of the df that you showed, will you provide a sample datframe containing the output you expect?

Comment: Your requirement list is pretty straight-forward. Did you try `groupby().shift()` for the previous/next request? and `between` to filter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but here is a demo that hopefully gives you enough to get yourself unstuck:

```
#create your example
df = pd.DataFrame({"client_id": [5186, 5186, 5186],
     "client_port":[54771,54772,54772],
     "timestamp":[1621382531757,1621382531758, 1621382531759],
     "ssize":[-47, 23, 275]})

#create a key of client_id and client_port
df["key"] =  df.apply(lambda row: f'{row["client_id"]}_{row["client_port"]}', axis=1)

#set an index based on key
df.set_index("key", inplace=True)

#filter rows by key
target_rows = df.loc["5186_54772"]

#locate packets of a certain size
target_rows.loc[(
    (target_rows.ssize >= 268) &
    (target_rows.ssize <= 280) 
)]
```